# Sending post parameters to servlet when using AngularJS routing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, servlets, post

So my angularJS routing code is like this:

```
    .when("/page1", {
        templateUrl : "page1.html",
        controller : "controller1"
    })
    .when("/page2", {
        templateUrl : "servlet1",
        controller : "controler2"
    })
```

If I use a form like this, with the action redirecting directly to the servlet:

```
<form action="" method="post" name="registro">
```

Everythin works as expected, as in:

```
Your name: Bob.
```

However, if I try like this:

```
<form action="#page2" method="post" name="registro">
```

Nothing at all is loaded to the . When I change method to "get" in both the form and the serlvet code, everything again works perfectly when using action="servlet1", but when using action="#page2", de  looks something like this:

```
Your name: null.
```

So it seems like no parameters are being passed when routing with AngularJS. My question is... Is there any way to send the POST paramaters to a servlet through AngularJS routing?